# Counting Unique Numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, distinct-values

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNEws.png) I am trying to count how many unique numbers are in a column.
I tried `IF(A2=A3,"1","0")`, but it doesn't work because there are multiple invoices in some cases.

Sample Column:

[image: Sample Invoice Column]

I am expecting to receive a count of 1 for each unique number.
For the 14 in the sample, I am expecting 9 unique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There's a neat trick for this, like in this formula:

```
=SUM(1/COUNTIF(F4:F10,F4:F10))
```

Check following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a formula to count unique values, considering that these are

- in `range("A1:A12")`:

`=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A1:A12;A1:A12)=1;1;0))`

- in the whole column A:

`=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(A:A;A:A)=1;1;0))`

Comment: When I tried your equation, it only provided 0. Below is what I am trying to achieve: a column with either 0 or 1 next to the invoice Invoices.

Comment: @ZulT - it should not have been a zero, you probably have not changed the ranges. Anyway, write this formula next to the column with invoices and then change the ranges to match correspondingly - `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A;A8)=1;1;0)`. You have to change `A:A` and `A8`. E.g., if your invoices are in column `M`, change `A:A` to `M:M` and `A8` to `N8`, for the invoice on the 8th row.

Answer (score 1):

With newer Excel versions:

```
=COUNT(UNIQUE(A:A))
```

[image]

New solution since OP updated question:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)>1,0,1)
```

In `C1` to be dragged down. Result:
[image]

Comment: I updated my results. I am seeing to have a 1 or 0 next to the invoice so I can create a pivot table that counts just the 1s.

Comment: Updated answer based on updated expected results